# I am trying to retrieve data from my Firebase realtime database but it is getting me null?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code for the main screen at which i want to retrieve the image name and the Login and signup words other than writing them with hard code from my realtime database. However here i always get the answer as null and the picture doesn't load. So what can i change in my code to get the values from my database without getting null. Moreover, my database is us central and i tried to put the url other than the instance and didn’t do any change.

```
    void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundHandler);
      runApp(NGU_APP());
    }
    
    // ignore: camel_case_types
    class NGU_APP extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: MyHomepage(),
          routes: {
            "login": (_) => LoginScreen(),
            "signup": (_) => RegistrationScreen(),
          },
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MyHomepage extends StatefulWidget {
      const MyHomepage({key}) : super(key: key);
      @override
      _MyHomepageState createState() => _MyHomepageState();
    }
    
    class _MyHomepageState extends State<MyHomepage> {
      
      DatabaseReference dbref;
    
      String Images = "images/logo.png";
    
      String Login = "Log In";
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
    
        dbref = FirebaseDatabase
.instance
            .reference()
            .child('ngu-su-default-rtdb');
    
        dbref.child("Login").onValue.listen((event) {
          print(event.snapshot.value.toString());
          setState(() {
            Login = event.snapshot.value.toString();
    
            print(Login);
          });
        });
        dbref.child("Imagees").onValue.listen((event) {
          print(event.snapshot.value.toString());
          setState(() {
            Images = event.snapshot.value.toString();
    
            print(Images);
          });
        });
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFF6D0131),
            body: SafeArea(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Center(
                            child: Hero(
                              tag: 'logo',
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                  radius: (100),
                                  child: ClipRRect(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(110),
                                    child: Image.asset("$Images"),
                                  )),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 48.0,
                      ),
                      Buttons(
                          colour: Colors.white,
                          text: Login.toString(),
                          page: LoginScreen()),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5.0,
                      ),
                      Buttons(
                          colour: Colors.white,
                          text: 'Sign Up',
                          page: RegistrationScreen())
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class RoundedButton extends StatelessWidget {
      RoundedButton({this.title, this.colour, @required this.onPressed});
    
      final Color colour;
      final String title;
      final Function onPressed;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
          child: Material(
            elevation: 5.0,
            color: colour,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            child: MaterialButton(
              onPressed: onPressed,
              minWidth: 200.0,
              height: 42.0,
              child: Text(
                title,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  color: Color(0xFF6D0131),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class Buttons extends StatelessWidget {
      Buttons({
        @required this.colour,
        @required this.text,
        @required this.page,
      });
    
      final String text;
      final Color colour;
    
      final Widget page;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () async {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) {
                  return page;
                },
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 50.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: colour,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
            ),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 18.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                text,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xFF6D0131),
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

This is the error i get:

```
I/flutter ( 5514): null
======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: null
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:224:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:675:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "null")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#6f075(), name: "null", scale: 1.0)
====================================================================================================
I/chatty  ( 5514): uid=10124(com.newgizauniversity.ngusu) 1.ui identical 2 lines
I/flutter ( 5514): null
```

Comment: I guess you have entered the wrong key, ` dbref.child("Imagees")`. Imagees instead of images.

Comment: No, the child name in the database is Imagees.